# PHP preg_replace regex, get number between parenthesis that might or might not contain _ and - sign

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

This is driving me nuts! I need a regex to extract a number from a string. The number might include a - (minus) or _ (underscore) sign, preferably using preg_replace.

The example string: "*This is 1 example (text) with a (number)(01230_12-3)*".

What I need to extract is the (01230_12-3), but without the parenthesis.

So far, this is what I have:

```
$FolderTitle[$Counter]) = "This is 1 example (text) with a (number)(01230_12-3)";
$FolderNumber[$Counter] = preg_replace("/([^0-9-_])/imsxU", '', $FolderTitle[$Counter]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- When using `preg_match()` an output variable is necessary, so I am using a shorthand conditional to determine if there was a match and setting the necessary value to the echo.
- You need to match the leading `(` then *forget* it with `\K` then match as many of the qualifying characters as possible.
- None of those pattern modifiers were necessary, so I removed them.
- You can replace my echo with your `$FolderNumber[$Counter] =`
- the leading parenthesis in the pattern must be escaped with `\`.
- `\d` is the same as `[0-9]`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/CjnC6))

```
$Counter = 0;
$FolderTitle[$Counter] = "This is 1 example (text) with a (number)(01230_12-3)";
echo preg_match("/\(\K[-\d_]+/", $FolderTitle[$Counter], $out) ? $out[0] : 'no match';
```

Output:

```
01230_12-3
```

Comment: How are we doing @Leon?  Do you have any input strings in your project that my answer doesn't accommodate?

Comment: I'm starting to understand the whole regex magic a bit more now, thanks to this.

This example doesn't get through for some reason;

"Naar huis met pijnstillers na een operatie  Afd Anaesthesiologie(0000485-08_16)(Anesthesiologie)(vier TABEL)"

Comment: My bad, I had another pre_replace before that, it works like a charm! Thanks for the lesson! ;)